# How to convert OData model to entityset in sap ui5

Tags: javascript, odata, sapui5

I want to use smart Table like in this [sapui5 explored sample](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/explored.html#/sample/sap.ui.comp.sample.smarttable/preview) but the problem is I have a OData model and the example shows only how we can handle the binding with mock data and also I didn't understand the metadata.xml file. I guess oData model has also its own metadata document.  Here my codes in controller :

```
this.DataPath = "QuarterPerformanceSet";
var oModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel(model.Config.getServiceUrl(), true, model.user, password); 
oModel.setCountSupported(false);
oSmartTable.setModel(oModel);
oSmartTable.setEntitySet(this.DataPath);
```

but it doesn't work. I got this error :

***Component-changes.json could not be loaded from ./Component-changes.json. Check for 'file not found' or parse errors. Reason: Not Found -***

***getChanges' failed: -***

Simply how can I set entitySet using my odata model?

my view:

```
<smartTable:SmartTable id="idSmartTable" tableType="Table" 
useExportToExcel="true" useVariantManagement="false" 
useTablePersonalisation="true" header="Line Items" showRowCount="true"
persistencyKey="SmartTableAnalytical_Explored" enableAutoBinding="true"/>
```

Thank you in advance if someone can help.

UPDATE 2 : I rebind table according to this [discussion](http://scn.sap.com/thread/3728486)

```
this.DataPath = "QuarterPerformanceSet";
var oModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel(model.Config.getServiceUrl(), true, model.user, password); 
oModel.setCountSupported(false);
var oSmartTable = this.getView().byId("idSmartTable");
oSmartTable.setModel(oModel);
oSmartTable.setEntitySet(this.DataPath);
oSmartTable.rebindTable();
```

sad to say but still I got same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the name of entity set, not the model instance. If you have for example an entity set Customers defined you just do:

```
oSmartTable.setEntitySet("Customers");
```

or add the attribute entitySet to your table declaration.

```
<smartTable:SmartTable id="idSmartTable" entitySet="ENTITY_SET" .../>
```

Comment: Should I set the model like oSmartTable.setModel(oModel);

Comment: Yes, but you don't need to do that if the model is know to the view that contains the table. In this case UI5 should propagate the model automatically.

Comment: I updated my question and still it doesn't work. Can you look at the question again please.

Comment: thank you I had forgotten to add an filter at first so because of that my table didn't show anything it worked now.

Comment: So is the question answered or do you still have problems?

Comment: no I don't :) your answer solved my problem thank you again.

Comment: @melomg Could you modify to add an filter to the update? I'm facing the same problem.